# Azure AD - Manage Oath token

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

In Azure AD in the Multi-Factor Authentication blade, I would like to delegate the rights to upload new OATH Tokens and activate them:
[OATH Tokens picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSSdM.png)

Which is the right role to assign to a technicians in order to do these tasks?
Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Emanuele

Answer (score 0):

As Discussed in this [***Microsofft Q & A***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/241537/which-role-to-assign-mfa-oath-tokens.html) You need `Global Admin` role for uploading the Oauth Token.

There are ways to make the process a bit easier for bulk uploading Hardware Oauth Token with Azure MFA:

***https://medium.com/@token2/how-to-bulk-activate-oath-hardware-tokens-with-azure-mfa-f551eaa00501***